# Mule:SFDC<->Oracle Integration API Specification Process

Tags: mule

Wanted to ask this general question where I am working on implementing SFDC Oracle integration. From the implementation point of view it is easy to visualize using Polling/Batching/Bulk exports etc.

But is SFDC<->Oracle integration amenable to RAML specification process given that we are not following REST conventions as in specifying GET/POST and RAML is based on REST Invocation(atleast based on my experience). The invocation style used here BATCH processing. So is RAML API specification process relevant here at all? Is there any value in establishing RAML specs for SFDC & Oracle?

Comment: How are you triggering the flow? What's the inbound connector?

Comment: I am using a polling flow to detect any changes in SFDC .. inbound is using a Salesforce connector to query Salesforce tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not actually routing inbound HTTP requests using the APIkit Router, I wouldn't add unnecessary code bloat. While RAML + the APIKit router is pretty powerful for routing requests, enforcing policies, generating variables from URI params, etc.... it's probably overkill.